# How to prove statement about octal numbers

Tags: cryptography, repunit-numbers

How to prove for any prime $$p \neq \{2,7\}, \exists n \text{ s.t. }p \mid n$$
where n is a number that consists only of 1s in octal base.

I started off but need some direction. I thought of using 
$$
8^{p-1} - 1 \text{ (mod p)}
$$

and that 
$$
8^{p-1} - 1
$$
given $(p-1)$ number of 7s in octal form; and that this divided by 7 is all 1s in octal form.

Comment: good start; are you familiar with [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)?

Comment: Yeah I understand that it's Fermat's little theorem but then I'm not too sure how to follow on with the octal part.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?  showing that $8^{p-1}-1$ is all $7$s and $(8^{p-1}-1)/7$ is all $1$s in octal form?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009511.

Answer (score 1):

You’re on the right track.  By Fermat’s little theorem, $8^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$ for prime $p\ne2$, so $p\mid8^{p-1}-1$.    Furthermore, $7\mid8^{p-1}-1,$ since $8\equiv1\pmod7$. Say $8^{p-1}-1=7k$.  Then $p\mid7k$, and $p\ne7$ means $p\mid k=\dfrac{8^{p-1}-1}7=\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{p-2} 7\times8^i}7=\sum\limits_{I=0}^{p-2}8^i$, which is a string of $1$s in octal notation.