# Divisibility and Pigeonhole principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Given a sequence of $p$ integers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_p$, show that there exist consecutive terms in the sequence whose sum is divisible by $p$.  That is, show that there are $i$ and $j$, with $1 \leq i \leq j \leq p$, such that $a_i + a_{i+1} + \cdots + a_j$ is divisible by $p$.

I'm having trouble with labeling which entities are the pigeons, and which are the pigeonholes.  I think somewhere down the line, there has to be more different sums than $p$, but that is just a guess.

Comment: You may find of interest [a similar Pigeonhole argument:](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/163827/242) if $\rm\:n\:$ is coprime to $10\,$ then every integer with at least $\rm\:n\:$ digits $\ne 0$  has a contiguous digit subsequence that forms an integer $\ne 0$ divisible by $\rm\:n.\ \ $

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933631/prove-that-there-are-i-and-j-with-1-le-i-le-j-le-n-such-that-a-ia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  The holes are remainders on division by $p$.  Consider $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i$ for $k=1,2,3 \ldots,p$  If any are divisible by $p$ you are done.  If not, You have $p$ sums with only $p-1$ values of remainder allowed.

Comment: A ha! So two of these sums will have the same remainder, so their difference is divisible by p, right?

Comment: @user1526710:  Exactly.  Then if the two that match are $k_1$ and $k_2$, the sum from $k1+1 through $k_2$ is the one you want.