# Prove that every integer $n>0$ with $\gcd(n,10) = 1$ has a multiple that can be written with only the digit $9$.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that a natural number multiplied by some integer results in a number with only one and zero as digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83932/proof-that-a-natural-number-multiplied-by-some-integer-results-in-a-number-with)

The question is as stated. I'm really stumped on it. It seems intuitively true, but I don't really know what direction to look in. I've calculated some examples for some values, but there doesn't seem to be any particular rhyme or reason to it that would suggest a constructive proof. I've thought about the possible remainders of $9\cdot\cdot\cdot9/n$, and wondered if I could show that the remainder must be $0$ for some $n$, but that hasn't taken me far. I've been poking and prodding at it from several directions, but I've gotten nowhere really. This is a real brain-teaser. Can anyone give me some helpful hints?

Comment: $\begin{align} 99 & = 3\cdot3\cdot11 \\ 999 & = 3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot37 \\ 9999 & = 3\cdot3\cdot101 \\ 99999 & = 3\cdot3\cdot41\cdot271 \\ 999999 & 3\cdot3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot37 \\ 9999999 & = 3\cdot3\cdot11\cdot73\cdot101\cdot137 \end{align}$  The claim seems to be that every positive integer whose last digit is not $0,2,4,5,6$, or $8$ will appear in one of these factorizations.  (Not as one of the prime factors, but as the product of some of them.)

Comment: If I can believe the software that gave me these results, then $9999999999$ is divisible by $9091$, and $999999999999$ is divisible by $9901$, and $99999999999999$ is divisible by $909091$.  I'm too lazy right now to explain what pattern I'm looking at, let alone find the obvious reason why it happens.  But probably there is one.

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** It is easy with the appropriate machinery. By [Euler's Theorem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) we have
$$10^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod{n}.$$
Thus $10^{\varphi(n)}-1$ is a multiple of $n$.

**Remark:** We can do it without mentioning Euler's Theorem. Look at the remainders when $10^1$, $10^2$, $10^3$, and so on are divided by $n$. There can be no more than $n$ different remainders. It follows that there exist positive integers $a$ and $b$, with $a\lt b$, such that $10^a$ has the same remainder as $10^b$.  So $10^b-10^a$ is divisible by $n$, and therefore  $10^a(10^{b-a}-1)$ is divisible by $n$. But because $10^a$ and $n$ have no common factor greater than $1$, we conclude that $10^{b-a}-1$ is divisible by $n$.

One could rephrase this at a more elementary level by looking at the ordinary "long division" process when we divide $1$ by $n$.

Comment: That's super slick and I might use it. I'd like to have a more intuitive understanding of why this occurs, though. Perhaps examining the proof(s) of Euler's formula will reveal to me why this works. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @limp_chimp: I have added an argument that does not mention Euler's Theorem.  It contains an idea that is useful elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for that second argument; that one I can wrap my head around :)

Comment: **Note** $\ $ The remark added in your later edit is in fact a special case of the proof in my prior answer - see my added remark there.

Answer (score 5):

By a [simple Pigeonhole argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/163827/242) we can prove much more: if $\,n\,$ is coprime to $10\,$ then every integer with at least $\,n\,$ nonzero digits has a contiguous digit subsequence that forms an nonzero integer divisible by $\,n.\,$ Hence in your case the $\,n\,$ digit number $\,999\ldots999\,$ does the trick, i.e. some contiguous subsequence $\,99\ldots99\,$ is divisible by $\,n.$

**Remark** $ $ The remark that Andre added to his answer is in fact a special case of the above proof. It is instructive to examine this. Following the proof linked above, we examine the $\,n\!+\!1\,$ numbers $\,0,9,99,999,\ldots, 10^{n}\!-1\,$ till, by pigeonholing, we find two that are congruent mod $\,n,\,$ say $\,10^{j}\!-1\equiv 10^{k}\!-1,\,$ so $\,10^{j-k}\equiv 1\,$ by adding $1$ then cancelling $\,10^{k}$ (valid by $10$ is coprime to $\,n).\,$ Therefore, $ $ indeed, $ $  $\,n\mid10^{j-k}-1 = 999\cdots999\ $ (i.e. $\,j\!-\!k\,$ nines). The same pigeonhole argument proves that if $\,a\,$ is coprime to $\,n\,$ then there exists some integer $\,\ell\ge 1\,$ such that $\, a^\ell\equiv 1\pmod {\!n}.\,$ The least such $\,\ell\,$ is called the **order** of $\,a\,$ modulo $\, n,\,$ denoted $\,\ell = o_n(a).\,$ [Furthermore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) we have $\,a^k\equiv 1\iff \ell\mid n\,\ $ [which is *equivalent* to $\,\ell = o_n(a)\,$].

Comment: Thanks, this is really great. I understand it much better now having read through your proof. This stuff is not so intuitive for me :P