# Pigeonhole principle - divisibility by $7$.

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

> Take a natural number $x$ that has $7$ digits. Show that we can delete consecutive digits from it's start or from it's end (or both), such that the number we end with is divisible by $7$ (we can delete 6 digits or less).

For example if $x=1122334$, We can delete the $2334$ in it's end and get $112$ which is divisible by $7$.

I am not sure how to approach it, can anyone provide a hint or a solution? The only thing I noticed is that if $x$ contains a $0$ or a $7$ as a digit then we are done. Thanks

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page for [divisibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule), you can check for divisibility by $7$ by subtracting twice the last digit from the other digits. You can repeat this until you get a single digit.

Comment: There are 7 numbers we can find by removing digits from the front.  If none is divisible by 7, then [at least] two have the same remainder when dividing by 7.  Subtract the smaller from the larger and look at what you have.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/163827 Bill's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the sequence of truncations from the right : for example, in the given case we get the set $\{4,34,334,2334,22334,122334,1122334\}$. Now, in this set, if any element is divisible by $7$ we are done, since it is formed by removal of digits from the right.

If not, then there are only six remainders modulo $7$, so two of these have the same remainder modulo $7$. Take the longer one, and remove the digits of the shorter one from it. That number gives a multiple of $7$.

So, for example, in the above example, $2334$ and $1122334$ have the same remainder modulo $7$, so the removal of digits leads to $112$ which is a multiple of $7$.

To give another example, let us take $2544111$, for which the set $\{2544111,544111,44111,4111,111,11,1\}$ contains no multiple of $7$. However, note that $44111$ and $11$ leave the same remainder modulo $7$ so removing the digits gives $441$ which is a multiple of $7$. Also, $544111$ and $1$ leave the same remainder modulo $7$, so $54411$ is a multiple of $7$.

---

Something to consider : Can this be generalized to say $9,11,13$ with similar proof?

Comment: This argument works for any positive integer n which is not divisible by 2 or 5.