# Existance of multiple of $n$ with only 0 and 1 as it's digits

Tags: abstract-algebra, pigeonhole-principle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Proof that a natural number multiplied by some integer results in a number with only one and zero as digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83932/proof-that-a-natural-number-multiplied-by-some-integer-results-in-a-number-with)

I read this somewhere recently:

*For any natural number $n$, there exists a multiple of $n$, such that the multiple has only 0 and 1 as its digits.*

> $2 \to 10$
>
> $3 \to 111$
>
> $4 \to 100$
>
> $5 \to 10$
>
> $6 \to 1110$
>
> $7 \to 1001$

Any ideas how to go about proving this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Consider the numbers $a_1=1$, $a_2=11$, $a_3=111$, and so on. Let  $r_1, r_2,r_3,$ and so on be the remainders when the $a_i$ are divided by $n$.

There are at most $n$ conceivable such remainders. So there must be two numbers $a_i$, $a_j$ such that $i\lt j$ and $r_i=r_j$.  Their difference $a_j-a_i$ is divisible by $n$, and has only $0$'s and/or $1$'s. Moreover, all the $1$'s precede all the $0$'s.

Answer (score 13):

Consider the numbers 1,11,111,...,111...11 (1 is repeated n+1 times). Since these are n+1 numbers we can use the pegionhole principle to deduce that 2 of them are congruent $modulo$ $n$. Find the absolute value of the difference between the 2 numbers that are congruent modulo n. The difference is made up of 1(s) and zeros. This number is also divisible by n. (done)

In general if n is indivisible by 2 and 5, there exists a multiple of n that is written as repeated sequences of digits. For example n has a multiple that is in the form 249249249...249 The proof is very similar to the previous argument

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, specially for the point you mentioned in the second paragraph! It was very interesting.