# Prove that there exists a multiple of $2016$, such that the multiple has only $4$ and $6$ as its digits.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Prove that there exists a multiple of $2016$, such that the multiple has only $4$ and $6$ as its digits.
Any ideas how to go about proving this?
I tried it with pigeonhole-principle, i tried to find a similar demonstration like this one : [Existance of multiple of $n$ with only 0 and 1 as it's digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233746/existance-of-multiple-of-n-with-only-0-and-1-as-its-digits) , but i couldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the pigeonhole principle to find a multiple of $63$ that is a repunit *in base 100*.

Multiply that number by $64$.

Note that $63\cdot 64=2\cdot 2016$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Mostly because it actually works. :-)

Comment: Exactly! Otherwise there could have been zeroes. 10101010101010101

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think about that! :-)